# Can we update XNA to render any new image added in database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I have created an application on XNA 4.0. The application is displaying images that are added in the database. I want to ask that is it possible to live updae XNA application if i add more images into the database. Would it show those images or i have to restart application to view new inserted items.
Kindly tell me the possible way to update XNA screen Live.

Comment: I don't know the exact process, but you can load new images runtime. Just load the image from the database, use the Texture.SetData, using the bitmap image in the correct format, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your new textures using Texture2D.FromStream http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.fromstream.aspx

The stream can be any .Net stream so it can come from a file or memory stream. If you have a binary blob from a database you can make a memory stream from that using this overload [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)